# Deploying Rails app to VPS using nginx. Error when trying to access dynamic pages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, web-applications, nginx, passenger, vps

I'm trying to deploy a Ruby on Rails app to my VPS for the first time. I'm following [this guide.](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/06/28/setup-a-ubuntu-vps-for-hosting-ruby-on-rails-applications-2/)

Everything seems to be working on my local machine.

I'm currently at the "Testing the VPS" part of the guide.

On my VPS, static pages that I have in my public folder work fine. However, I'm receiving an error message when I try to access a dynamic page.

When trying to go to `http://server-ip-address.com/users` (as specified by the guide) I am encountering this error from nginx:

> An error occurred.
>
> Sorry, the page you are looking for is currently unavailable.
>   Please try again later.
>
> If you are the system administrator of this resource then you should check the error log for details.

The logs at `/opt/nginx/logs/error.log` state:

```
2013/07/08 20:47:32 [crit] 17760#0: *151 connect() to /tmp/passenger.1.0.12435/generation-    0/request failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: client-    ip-address, server: server-ip-address, request: "GET /user HTTP/1.1", upstream:     "passenger:/tmp/passenger.1.0.12435/generation-0/request:", host: "server-ip-address"
```

I'm not sure how to fix this. Any help?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in 4.0.7. Fixed in 4.0.8, which was released an hour ago.

Comment: I hope that's the reason. I ended up just scrapping everything and restarting. However, I'm trying to find more information on this bug but my google-fu is insufficient. Do you have a link? Thank you!

Comment: Changes are always documented in the release announcements. See [the Phusion blog](http://blog.phusion.nl/2013/07/09/phusion-passenger-4-0-8-released/).